# Differentiability in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

A function is defined as differentiable at $x_0$if there exists a linear map M such that:
$$f(x_0+h)=f(x_0)+M(h)-\phi(h).h$$
Further, it is diffentiable iff $\phi $ is continuous.

(Correct me if I am being sloppy or wrong.)

Why is $\|\phi(h)\|\rightarrow 0$ as $h\rightarrow 0$ imply $\phi$ is continuous there?

Comment: if you define $\phi(0)=0 $ , it will be continuous at $h=0$..

Comment: I don't think, I usually "define" $\phi$. It's function/remainder after $f(x_0+h)$ has been approximated by linear map $M$.

Comment: @700resu  you don't define the whole function , just $\phi(0)$ because you  can't get the value of it at $0$ from the above equation..